Gateway in Interface Adapter Layer of Clean Architect
As I can see, in the humble object section of Uncle Bob, he mentioned that Database Gateway is an interface, and its implementation is a humble object.
context about db gateway written by Uncle Bob
As I understand, the Database Gateway will reside in Application Business Layer (the same layer as the usecase), and the implementation will reside in Framework Layer (outmost layer).
Is my understanding correct and if so, what does the term "Gateway" in Interface Adapter layer present
clean architecture structure
Thank you very much
###########


As I understand, the Database Gateway will reside in Application Business Layer (the same layer as the usecase), and the implementation will reside in Framework Layer (outmost layer).

Yes, the interface will reside in the application layer and the implementation in the interface adapters layer.

Is my understanding correct and if so, what does the term "Gateway" in Interface Adapter layer present

The term refers to the gateway implementations. You might be a bit confused that the term appears in the name of the interface in the application layer and in the diagram it appears in the adapters layer where the implementations reside. I usually prefer the term Repository in the application layer, because to me it is closer to a domain language then database gateway.
In general a gataway is an object that encapsulates access to an external system or resource. See Gateway.

Hello René Link, thank you so much for your time.
As I see, the gateway will refer to the gateway implementation, where we encapsulate the request made to other service (probably external APIs).
So is it true that these gateways will implement some interfaces offered by Application Business Layer, so that the usecase can make call to the service API ?
If it is the case, then it is also true that some interface in the Application Business Layer will be implemented by Gateway in the Interface  Adapter layer, and some others implemented by the DB in the framework layer, right ?

(if it is not true then can you tell me where the Gateway implementation will be used in the clean architecture flow ? maybe inside the controller or else where?)
